# implementing a social sign-in user model

Tags: php, facebook, database-schema

I want users to be able to login from any provider (facebook, google, etc) from my app and also to create an account with my server. What I want to figure out is the best way to construct a user model doing this.

For example,

A user logs in using facebook a new user record will be made and there will be a flag in the record telling me that the account is a facebook account. If the same user creates a standard account with my server and then logs back in using facebook, how shall I handle this? Is the best practice to merge/relate these two accounts with each other or to treat them as two different records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Im working on the same things. I will use these rules:

- Check emails. Its be best way to identify user.
- Set special long-time cookie after successful registration. Later you can ask user to merge
  accounts.
- Username, realname, birthday etc can be used as additional
  params to compare.

About scheme: I create a table `users` (id, username, email) and `user_data` (id, user_id,  email, service_id, service_name, service_type, is_active). `service_id` is a Provider-specific identifier, `service_type` is a Provider name (google/facebook/etc), and `service_name` is a displayName from Provider's site (may differs from `user`.`username`). `service_id + service_type` must be unique.

Comment: PS. Its a draft scheme ;) And I want to use not only FB as a Provider

Comment: so bottom line is you need a common unifying key that is provided by the social network api, as well as site based signup.  I can not think of a universal unifying key.  The closest is perhaps email.  Is that how stackoverflow handles its signups?

Comment: I dont think you can automatically make a decision about profile merging. Stackoverflow uses manual merging (see `my logins` link in your profile). Also I think it stores user identifier in cookie (autologon in about 5 secs after page load).

Comment: yeh, that is perhaps the most complete solution.  not relying on the cookie, but making it available and allowing users to maintain multiple logins.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the feedback so far. I think manual merging is the only way to do this. I am still undecided as to how I should persist this data. Ideally I'd like to collect as much information from all providers ie. names, ages, locations etc to enrich analytics. It's actually quite an irritating problem...

Comment: Well, just store response body as serialized string. So you can analyze provider-specific data later.

Comment: yeah the thing is i want indexed search on those fields!

Comment: It's not really a blocker, I can just store them as BLOB and export and use them in another db as and when i need to. if i even ever need to.

Comment: Yes, you can use another tables or NoSQL tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know if they are the same account is with some identifier.  You can request to have the email returned from the FB login and store that info in your email field in the table, and then if they try to create an account with that email, you can notify them that they already have an account.

Otherwise, I don't see how you would know if they are the same person.

Comment: Well there might be a case where they can link up there social accounts whilst logged in as a standard user. I spose in this case I'll know what I need to do. Any Ideas on a schema?